# Is there a way to chain conditionals in Ruby, Rails or ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Sometimes I find myself doing something like:

```
def my_method
  item = SomeModel.where(some_attr: 'some_val').first
  (item) ? nil : item.method
end
```

This is to say that if `item` exists, return the results of `item.method`, but if it doesn't exist, just return nil or false.

I can more succinctly write this like this:

```
def my_method
  SomeModel.where(some_attr: 'some_val').first.try(:some_method)
end
```

I've heard that a rails `rescue` operation can be expensive, though.  Is there something as succinct and elegant as the `try` that I could use in it's place?

Comment: What's wrong with the `try` in your second example?

Comment: There is no `rescue` when using `try`, it has different implementations for `Object` and `NilClass`.

Comment: *"Is there something as succinct and elegant as the try that I could use in it's place"*. Ruby >= 2.3 implemented a safe navigation operator which is far less expensive than `try` it would be implemented as  `SomeModel.where(some_attr: 'some_val').first&.method`

Comment: If `some_method` is an attribute method and not a logical one then  `SomeModel.where(some_attr: 'some_val').pluck(:some_method).first` will suffice as it will return the `some_method` based on the order or `nil`

Comment: @engineersmnky yes, I use `pluck` frequently.  This is not an attribute, though.

Comment: @LGFaler could you explain why you want to omit (or can't use) `try`?

Comment: @Stefan you know, it looks like I made a stupid assumption.  Upon your inquiry I looked up the source for `.try()` and saw that it is actually exactly what I wanted.  For some reason I had it in my mind that it performed the operation in a begin/rescue.  I feel dumb!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are positive there will be either single or none records returned, you might safely use an enumerator instead:

```
SomeModel.where(some_attr: 'some_val')
         .limit(1)
         .map(&:some_method)
         .first
```

Comment: Surely. With `limit(1)` in place, the above is the fastest and cleanest approach, IMHO.

Comment: @mudasobwa you are basically calling the method on every instance of Active Record relation, which is bad

Comment: @gates I am not sure I follow why is it bad.

Comment: SomeModel.where(some_attr: 'some_val') you are still querying for everything here, why not find_by

Comment: If there is only one instance, though, you've lost nothing.

Comment: @gates I think that the only difference between `.find_by()` and `.where().first` is that the former returns a `nil` or a single instantiated model, and the latter returns a collection of 0 or 1 instantiated models.  They effectively produce the same SQL, don't they?  A collection affords me the use of `.map()`.